# Can not import urllib or requests in Python3.5

Tags: python-3.5

I am modifying my source code of Python 3.5. In order to send PUT request to a web service, I want to import urllib or requests but I am facing the following error.
The last part of the error message is the same when I add `import urllib.request` and `import requests`.

**[Environment]**

Windows 10 64-bit
Python 3.5

**[Error Message]**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/xxx/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/xxx.py", line 16, in 
>       import urllib.request
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in 
>       import http.client
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1218, in 
>       import ssl
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 135, in 
>       PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLS
>
> File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py", line 274, in __ getattr __
>       raise AttributeError(name) from None
>
> AttributeError: PROTOCOL_TLS

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please paste the code you used to send the PUT request

Comment: Following is the code of PUT request, but even I comment it out (it means just importing requests), the error message above occurs.  `requests.put('https://clinic-mankuu-test.herokuapp.com/clinics/' + clinic_id + '/update_infowindow')`